# Call text but totally exclude tables

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to load an XMl. All I need is the text, ignoring the  tags, and the `text` attribute words nice.

However, I would like to totally exclude anything within  `<table><\table>` tags. I had the idea of substituting everything in between with a regex, but I am wondering whether there is a cleaner solution partly because [Don't parse [X]HTML with regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). For instance:

```
s =""" <content><p>Hasselt ( ) is a <link target="Belgium">Belgian</link> <link target="city">city</link> and <link target="Municipalities in Belgium">municipality</link>. 
<table><cell>Passenger growth
<cell>Year</cell><cell>Passengers</cell><cell>Percentage </cell></cell>
<cell>1996</cell><cell>360 000</cell><cell>100%</cell>
<cell>1997</cell><cell>1 498 088</cell><cell>428%</cell>
</table>"""
clean = Soup(s)
print clean.text
```

will give

```
Hasselt ( ) is a Belgian city and municipality. 
Passenger growth
YearPassengersPercentage 
1996360 000100%
19971 498 088428%
```

whereas I only want:

```
Hasselt ( ) is a Belgian city and municipality.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the `content` element and remove all `table` elements from it, then get the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s =""" <content><p>Hasselt ( ) is a <link target="Belgium">Belgian</link> <link target="city">city</link> and <link target="Municipalities in Belgium">municipality</link>.
<table><cell>Passenger growth
<cell>Year</cell><cell>Passengers</cell><cell>Percentage </cell></cell>
<cell>1996</cell><cell>360 000</cell><cell>100%</cell>
<cell>1997</cell><cell>1 498 088</cell><cell>428%</cell>
</table>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "xml")

content = soup.content
for table in content("table"):
    table.extract()

print(content.get_text().strip())
```

Prints:

```
Hasselt ( ) is a Belgian city and municipality.
```

Comment: You must have started writing code before the ink was dry in the question ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham :) actually, have `bs4` handy code snippets prepared. We are doing serious sports here! Thanks.